# higher K-theory of complex numbers

Tags: algebraic-k-theory

What is known about the higher algebraic K-theory of the complex numbers $\mathbb{C}$?

It's obvious that $K_0(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{Z}$.  According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Algebraic_K-theory#Higher_K-theory), it seems like we should have $K_1(\mathbb{C}) = \mathbb{C}^\times$.  It seems like one can write down something for $K_2$, though I don't really understand it very well.  Roughly, I want to get a sense of how hard this problem is (blind guess: it is hard).

If it turns out this problem is easy, then the follow-up question is what is the higher algebraic K-theory of $BG$, i.e. the exact category of $G$-representations, for $G$ an algebraic group?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I'm definitely not an expert on algebraic $K$-theory, but here is at least some idea for what is true for $K_i(\mathbf{C})$. The main result is the following:

**Theorem** ([Suslin 1984](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(84)90043-4))**.** *Modulo uniquely divisible groups, we have*
$$K_i(\mathbf{C}) = \begin{cases}
  0 & \text{if}\ i\ \text{even}\\
  \mathbf{Q}/\mathbf{Z} & \text{if}\ i\ \text{odd}
\end{cases}$$

I don't know if you can get a more complete description of the uniquely divisible part. The key idea is to use the following

**Theorem** ([Suslin 1984](http://dx.doi.org/10.1016/0022-4049(84)90043-4))**.** *$\mathrm{BGL}(\mathbf{C})^+ \to \mathrm{BGL}(\mathbf{C})^\mathrm{top}$ induces isomorphisms on homology and homotopy groups with finite coefficients.*

Here, $\mathrm{BGL}(\mathbf{C})$ denotes the classifying space for the discrete group $\mathrm{GL}(\mathbf{C})$, while $\mathrm{BGL}(\mathbf{C})^\mathrm{top} \simeq \mathrm{BU}$ is the classifying space of the topological group $\mathrm{GL}(\mathbf{C})^\mathrm{top}$. The first Theorem then follows by a [result due to Weibel](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=750694); look at the last section in Suslin's paper.

For other references, the [relevant chapter](http://www.math.rutgers.edu/~weibel/Kbook/Kbook.VI.pdf) (§3) in Weibel's book (I've linked to a draft version) is useful, as is [this ICM lecture](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1986.1/Main/icm1986.1.0222.0244.ocr.pdf) (§2) by Suslin, and [this survey](http://www.math.uiuc.edu/~dan/Papers/KTheoryOfFields.pdf) (§22) by Grayson. Note also that Jardine has an [alternate proof](http://dx.doi.org/10.1090/conm/055.1/862637) of the first theorem using sheaf cohomology on the big étale site.

For your second question, I think this example shows that one approach is to look for a comparison like in the second theorem above betweeen $\mathrm{BG}$ and $\mathrm{BG}^\mathrm{top}$, and then to get information about $\mathrm{BG}^\mathrm{top}$ somehow. Even in the case above, though, [Weibel's calculation](http://www.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=750694) looks difficult.